# PyDrive - Google drive API - Create folder tree

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a folder structure on google drive with python. I've checked all documentations, and all similar stackoverflow questions, but it does not work.

The folder structure I want to create is something like

`2017
----06
--------13
--------14`

I did not manage to create a folder at any other place than root. The layout is beign flat, and I do not see why.

```
# this method should create a directory tree, from a string like '2017/06/14'
def create_drive_folder(path):
    # this method should create a folder with the given parents
    # at first it is called with root as parent, for the 2017 folder
    # and when the 06 folder should be created it gets [root and the successfully created 2017 folder id]
    def create_drive_folder_level(filename, parents):
        dirs = drive.ListFile(
            {'q': "'{}' in parents and trashed=false and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'".format(
                parents[-1]['id'])})

        try:
            # this will give me the parent folder, if it exists
            current = [x for x in list(dirs)[0] if x['title'] == filename][0]
        except HttpError:
            current = None
        except IndexError:
            current = None
        if not current:
            meta = {'title': filename, 'parents': [x['id'] for x in [parents[-1]],
                    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'}
            current = drive.CreateFile(meta)
            current.Upload({'convert': True})
            return current
        return current

    path = path.split('/')
    p = [dict(id='root')]
    for i in range(len(path)):
        p.append(create_drive_folder_level(path[i], p))

create_drive_folder('2017/06/14')
```

UPDATE:

The Output this code produces:

```
{'title': '2017', 'parents': ['root'], 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'}
GoogleDriveFile({'title': '2017', 'parents': [{'kind': 'drive#parentReference', 'id': '0AC4TRMtjeM-PUk9PVA', 'isRoot': True}], 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder', 'kind': 'drive#file', 'id': '0By4TRMtjeM-PRjNPT0pXaFpxY2s', ...})

{'title': '06', 'parents': ['0By4TRMtjeM-PRjNPT0pXaFpxY2s'], 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'}
GoogleDriveFile({'title': '06', 'parents': [{'kind': 'drive#parentReference', 'id': '0AC4TRMtjeM-PUk9PVA', 'isRoot': True}], 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder', 'kind': 'drive#file', 'id': '0By4TRMtjeM-PQUs0OWZ0VFlLTmM', ...})

{'title': '14', 'parents': ['0By4TRMtjeM-PQUs0OWZ0VFlLTmM'], 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'}
GoogleDriveFile({'title': '14', 'parents': [{'kind': 'drive#parentReference', 'id': '0AC4TRMtjeM-PUk9PVA', 'isRoot': True}], 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder', 'kind': 'drive#file', 'id': '0By4TRMtjeM-PN2o4MVplZERiUzA', ...})
```

It seems to me, that I am giving the correct ID-s, when creating the subdirectories. The layout still becomes flat. WHY?

Comment: Do you have any error logs?

Comment: I do not. Only these which I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually managed to find the solution. The problem was, that the parents must be dicts, not just string ids.
So instead of:

`{'title': '06', 'parents': ['0By4TRMtjeM-PRjNPT0pXaFpxY2s']}`

It should be:

`{'title': '06', 'parents': [{'id': '0By4TRMtjeM-PRjNPT0pXaFpxY2s'}]}`